# ¿Cómo se utiliza scipy.misc.image()?

Tags: python, scipy

Quiero leer una imagen y guardarla como una matriz. Leí que utilizando scipy.misc.image() podría hacer eso pero no he podido establecer los parámetros para que lea la imagen.
Así es como estoy leyendo la imagen:

```
key = scipy.misc.imread("C:\Program Files\Python36\lena512.bmp")
```

Quiero tener una matriz con los valores en escala de grises de la imagen.

Answer (score 3):

- Primero de todo, `scipy.misc.imread` usa ***PIL***/[***Pillow***](http://%22C:%5CProgram%20Files%5CPython36%5Clena512.bmp%22) para leer la imagen (al igual que `matplotlib.image` y muchos otros métodos para trabajar con imagenes en Python). Deberías tenerlo instalado al ser una dependencia,  pero asegúrate. Si al intentar importarlo con:

  ```
  >>> import PIL
  ```

  Obtienes un error:

  > ```
  > Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
  >     import PIL
  > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
  > ```

  Necesitas instalarlo, puedes hacerlo con `pip`, en la terminal (CMD):

  ```
  py -3.6 -m pip install pillow
  ```
- Otro error frecuente se produce al **importar el modulo**, la forma correcta es

  ```
  >>> import scipy.misc
  ```

  y no:

  ```
  >>> import scipy
  ```
- Por ultimo la **ruta de la imagen debería seguir el modelo *nix**, en vez de:

  > "C:\Program Files\Python36\lena512.bmp"

  Debes usar:

  > "C:/Program Files/Python36/lena512.bmp"

  Observa el cambio de `\` (back slash) por `/` (forward slash). De lo contrario puedes obtener un error de sintaxis del tipo:

  > SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

---

En resumen, debes leer tu imagen así:

```
>>> import scipy.misc
>>> key = scipy.misc.imread("C:/Program Files/Python36/lena512.bmp")
```

Podemos ver como la imagen queda almacenada en un array de Numpy

```
>>> key
array([[162, 162, 162, ..., 170, 155, 128],
       [162, 162, 162, ..., 170, 155, 128],
       [162, 162, 162, ..., 170, 155, 128],
       ..., 
       [ 43,  43,  50, ..., 104, 100,  98],
       [ 44,  44,  55, ..., 104, 105, 108],
       [ 44,  44,  55, ..., 104, 105, 108]], dtype=uint8)

>>> key.shape
(512, 512)
```

En este caso la [imagen original](https://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lena512.bmp) es una imagen en escala de grises (modo `L`), el array por tanto representa pixels de 8-bit. Existe la posibilidad de convertir la imagen a otro modelo siempre que sea posible (RGB, RGBA, YCbCr, CMYK, etc). También se puede pasar de una imagen en color a escala de grises. Para mas información ver la documentación oficial:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html

Answer (score 1):

Una buena opción es [matplotlib.image](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html):

```
import PIL
import matplotlib.image as img
image = img.imread("C:\Program Files\Python36\lena512.bmp")

# Ahora es un array 3D de numpy
print image.shape
Out[0]: (300, 500, 3)
```